# Xcode 10 Build failed - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, xcode10

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eCGq.png) I've been trying to get my react-native app to build in Xcode 10. However, the build fails with an error message of header files not found, viz, 'React/UIView+React.h' file not found'

I've added React in the target dependencies and in the schemes, as suggested on a lot of Stack Overflow questions.
But the error still persists, and build fails.

My react-native version is 0.43.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using modules that require linking?  Things that usually need linking are maps, icons, modules that connect to native apps and hardware etc.  Can you update your question with a look at your package.json?

Comment: have you tried using legacy build? File -> Project Settings (or Workspace Settings)-> Build System